# Python Selenium Autologin issue incase the webform has no ID value in it

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to build python autologin script using selenium and below is the issue that I am facing now.

The below is the HTML source code, Selenium suggests to find the "ID" value of the login form for auto login. But in the below case there are no ID value available.How to code this to autologin in this case?

The below python code fails as there is no ID value in the HTML code given below

python code :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


browser = webdriver.Chrome() #replace with .Firefox(), or with the browser of your choice
url = "https://el.xxxx.com"
browser.get(url) #navigate to the page


username = browser.find_element_by_id("LOGIN") #username form field
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password") #password form field
typevalue= browser.find_element_by_id("SYSTEM")

username.send_keys("Mram")
password.send_keys("fake1")
typevalue.send_keys("ELIS")

submitButton = browser.find_element_by_id("submit") 
button.click()


when i click the inspect element this is the only available input, how to autologin using this below info. My python code failed

<input name='LOGIN'></td>
<input name='PWD' type='password'></td>
name='SYSTEM'><option>ELVIS</option><option>TDT</option>

HTML code below 
> <!doctype html public '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'
> 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'><html><head><meta
> http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' /><link
> rel='STYLESHEET' type='text/css' href='/./css/login.css'
> /></head><body><div id='contentWrapper'><div id='loginCenterBox'><div
> id='loginIcon'></div><div id='loginTable'><form accept-charset='UTF-8'
> name='loginForm' method='POST'
> action='/cgi-bin/login'><table><tr><td>User name:</td><td
> colspan=2><input name='LOGIN'></td></tr><tr><td>Password:</td><td
> colspan=2><input name='PWD'
> type='password'></td></tr><tr><td>System:</td><td
> colspan=2><select
> name='SYSTEM'><option>ELVIS</option><option>TDT</option></select></td></tr><tr><td><input name='PAGE' type='hidden' value='1'><input name='LANG' type='hidden'
> value='0'><input name='TARGET' type='hidden' value=''></td><td
> colspan=2><button
> type='submit'>Login</button></td></tr></table></form></div><div
> id='login_warning'></div><div id='bottomLoginLinkBox'><div
> id='registerBox'><a
> href="javascript:top.location='/cgi-bin/login?PAGE=10'" title="Not
> required if you have an account for old
> Elvis&#xA;(https://el.ha.com)">Create
> account</a></div><div id='forgotBox'><a
> href="mailto:HBI@he.com?Subject=Training%20request"
> target="_top">Training request</a></div></div><script
> type='text/javascript'>
> document.forms['loginForm'].elements['LOGIN'].focus();
> </script></div></div></body></html>
```

**Update**
Somehow the code is not still working, Tried this XPATH method as well as given below as there is no unique ID or class name available to get it done!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

chrome_path =r"D:\python\off\chromedriver.exe"
browser =webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)



url = "https://el.xxxx.com"
browser.get(url)
#Experimenting using XPATH
username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="loginTable"]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input""") #username form field
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="loginTable"]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input""") #password form field
typevalue= browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="loginTable"]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select""")
username.send_keys("Mram")
password.send_keys("fakepass")
password.submit()
```

This throws error;and the full error report ;
How to login without errors here ;compeltely stuck now .

```
[16648:7164:0725/140120.357:ERROR:install_util.cc(597)] Unable to read registry value HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken for writing result=2

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65270/devtools/browser/95c2a4d3-0539-42fb-8f96-4c775d2813f4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "officelinkcheck.py", line 21, in <module>
    username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="loginTable"]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input""") #username form field
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 393, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 966, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="loginTable"]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no **ID** given in HTML. You can use **Name** attribute which is given in **HTML**.

```
username  = driver.find_element_by_name('LOGIN')  
password  = driver.find_element_by_name('PWD')  
username.send_keys("Mram")
password.send_keys("fake1")
```

and for clicking on **Login** button :

```
submitButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Login')]")  
submitButton.click()
```

Note that **ELVIS** and **TDT** are in drop down.

for selecting **ELVIS** , you can use **select** class.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('SYSTEM'))  
select.select_by_visible_text('ELVIS')
```

Note that you will have to import from `selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select`

**UPDATE 1 :**

As per the HTML you have share with new requirements, you can try this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver   = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/Users/user***/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,40)

driver.get("file:///C:/Users/abhishep/Desktop/Python+Selenium/MArx.html") 

username  = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "LOGIN")))
password  = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "PWD"))) 
username.send_keys("Mrax")
password.send_keys("Babu") 

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('SYSTEM'))
select.select_by_visible_text('TDT')

time.sleep(1)
login_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Login')]")))  
login_button.click()
```

**UPDATE2 :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver   = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/Users/abhishep/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

driver.get("your private URL") 

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("frameset[frameborder] frameset[cols] frameset frame[src*='login']")) 

username  = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "LOGIN")))
password  = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "PWD"))) 
username.send_keys("Mrax")
password.send_keys("Babu") 

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('SYSTEM'))
select.select_by_visible_text('TDT')

login_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Login')]")))  
login_button.click()
```

Comment: I am getting few errors   Unable to read registry value HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken for writing result=2Unable to read registry value HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken for writing result=2         and           username = browser.find_element_by_name('LOGIN') #username form field
 File "C:\python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 495, in find_element_by_name

Comment: Is URL public ? cause registry values are being populated in error trace which I believe , that it is not related to selenium.

Comment: No URL is not public ; and help me to know the differrence of 'LOGIN' and "LOGIN" in webform it is "LOGIN" why we give 'LOGIN'

Comment: If you are talking about single ,and double quotes then any one of them is fine as long as you are not getting any exception :)

Comment: Ok due to registry error could not login ;i will have to find a workaround thank you ! i have one query pls help in one page after login i have button called "Excel" when i click the excel will be downloaded ,its html format is       <a class="btn btn-default buttons-excel buttons-html5 btn-primary" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" href="#"><span>Excel</span></a>     how to automate this click and download or read the content and store in array

Comment: Once you click on download button, something like 'driver.find_element_by_link_text("Excel").click() ' , then file will be downloaded (Note that there should not be any download pop up , if it is present, then you will have to handle that also ) , go to download directory and then read excel file .(If you want you can google it reading excel file in python). I think that would do the job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176579/discussion-between-marx-babu-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: @MarxBabu : As per the requirement , I have updated the code under update 1 section. Thank you.

Comment: The update 2 provided here works well.it is worth giving more than the points.Thank you for your support and help.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use xpath or css selector:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html
Easiest way to get them is using browsers element selectors:[image]

Comment: This is not helpful much as the error comes as element does not exist